# Shows Missing library : ff while building echidna using stack install

Tags: c, haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, cabal-install

I am trying to build echidna using `stack install`.

https://github.com/crytic/echidna

I am continuously getting the missing library error while installing at a progress state of `171/178`.

I believe it to be more of stack error than library error. Error shown is as follows

I have tried installing the library but not getting any C library of such sort.ye

SO, i've installed every library using

`sudo apt-get install lib*ff*-dev`

isn't working yet.

```
--  While building package hevm-0.31 using:
      /home/aman/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1 configure --with-ghc=/home/aman/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/aman/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/aman/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/pkgdb --package-db=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/pkgdb --libdir=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/lib --bindir=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/bin --datadir=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/share --libexecdir=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/etc --docdir=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/doc/hevm-0.31 --htmldir=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/doc/hevm-0.31 --haddockdir=/home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/doc/hevm-0.31 --dependency=QuickCheck=QuickCheck-2.11.3-3XHQpBYb83U2mMvNz2AjQX --dependency=abstract-par=abstract-par-0.3.3-Ie3MD7O3orK6ZR8i7FuBEv --dependency=aeson=aeson-1.3.1.1-7JlrwYHW7OR9ca4RRZ9oOf --dependency=ansi-wl-pprint=ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.2-9fh9v74MJQDJeSHE7X3Co6 --dependency=async=async-2.2.1-7DQr5PBcpiwJNOuf7ZiSPa --dependency=base=base-4.11.1.0 --dependency=base16-bytestring=base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6-I0igvRcEwRNBMqqPC2yQBh --dependency=base64-bytestring=base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1-4OCIe2BZn8jKI191JIXI37 --dependency=binary=binary-0.8.5.1 --dependency=brick=brick-0.37.2-HmDqAExuwtV4o98FRmS9eK --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.2 --dependency=cereal=cereal-0.5.7.0-ILaYAmVTyR1IcEsGXXUCfI --dependency=containers=containers-0.5.11.0 --dependency=cryptonite=cryptonite-0.25-GgyZs9E1viv2owjaLxA3vq --dependency=data-dword=data-dword-0.3.1.2-CMzWV6RCGtK8L6wsVSErKS --dependency=deepseq=deepseq-1.4.3.0 --dependency=directory=directory-1.3.1.5 --dependency=fgl=fgl-5.6.0.0-E3fRSNebqkULRqplV3ljSc --dependency=filepath=filepath-1.4.2 --dependency=ghci-pretty=ghci-pretty-0.0.2-I5PJbL8ge6MChp3KxZbHqH --dependency=haskeline=haskeline-0.7.4.3-5EI2v7Zmtnz57a7mmnEGOS --dependency=lens=lens-4.16.1-B0f4CyKKTUGAKBzzY965AX --dependency=lens-aeson=lens-aeson-1.0.2-Jly9eqrxMbj6GutGwOKn69 --dependency=megaparsec=megaparsec-6.5.0-G48ltiRFbVUHATB1lTnNRx --dependency=memory=memory-0.14.16-GTCi0eCrvrnI3inLDBWVMK --dependency=monad-par=monad-par-0.3.4.8-Jjk0JT5qYVK4xEO13GFUu8 --dependency=mtl=mtl-2.2.2 --dependency=multiset=multiset-0.3.4.1-DOPR5uXspss8vZY4jdOdOo --dependency=operational=operational-0.2.3.5-4jEcCWo4nKu1T4LZlKqe58 --dependency=optparse-generic=optparse-generic-1.3.0-1jcIewFKPXBLcRetZisV2l --dependency=process=process-1.6.3.0 --dependency=quickcheck-text=quickcheck-text-0.1.2.1-2lR7Kay7WBV5AMKAdKDpZZ --dependency=regex-tdfa=regex-tdfa-1.2.3.1-9PkkapJrmiKFVG38JA02jN --dependency=restless-git=restless-git-0.7-83nBoDMPYLtJIx01bvXzKs --dependency=rosezipper=rosezipper-0.2-GAlMD5j8Qb83GzjCYQknnx --dependency=s-cargot=s-cargot-0.1.4.0-J9AhWfrUxDQ6YMTyzXkHth --dependency=scientific=scientific-0.3.6.2-5di0UflhS5I1xpiiCPzjKz --dependency=semver-range=semver-range-0.2.7-dBvW3ofcsgDQf0zazTsJd --dependency=temporary=temporary-1.3-5Z6bOFbSCb7VhnH5UnI2r --dependency=text=text-1.2.3.0 --dependency=text-format=text-format-0.3.2-Fd261TSu6ptAAzilVN6BFx --dependency=time=time-1.8.0.2 --dependency=transformers=transformers-0.5.5.0 --dependency=tree-view=tree-view-0.5-Kkrk0dCM0oj2Q4xwPbd7Gg --dependency=unordered-containers=unordered-containers-0.2.9.0-IkfpzvG0LzrHAbTzfMidvY --dependency=vector=vector-0.12.0.1-4awQG9XUvVEBfJgKGHBhOb --dependency=vty=vty-5.21-A2OCwk39Wv3J3RjR3BvHey --dependency=witherable=witherable-0.2-2RYbFmOnVolGAqiDDS1CLe --dependency=wreq=wreq-0.5.2.1-IjuXB0jwsxA7O3uIVjcJXu --extra-include-dirs=/home/aman/Downloads/Compressed/ff13c/source/ --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/opt/readline/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/opt/readline/lib
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/aman/Desktop/new/echidna2/echidna/.stack-work/logs/hevm-0.31.log

    Configuring hevm-0.31...
    Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3: Missing dependency on a foreign
    library:
    * Missing (or bad) C library: ff
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
    library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
    compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
    with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
```

The stack install must find this library and end up successfully installing the library I'm using.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the question is being disliked?

If no specific reason. Please don't dislike it, It causes difficulty in getting possible answers. Specially if someone is a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is clear from the error provided above, that the installation was not able to find the `libff` file.

The best solution is to build the `libff` library manually and copy the required builds at the place it should be.

The best way to debug the problem is to look at the executed command closely and try to find the possible places where the libff should be...

Looking into the very 2nd error line, i.e. the complete command it was trying to execute
here, I sighted the following options being executed

`--extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/opt/readline/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/opt/readline/lib`

In order to solve this, I looked for the required `libff` library and cloned it from GitHub. I cloned the required dependencies and places them in the directory it should be.

> https://github.com/scipr-lab/libff

I then followed the "Build guide" to build the required library.

Then with the superuser on, I created the directories, `/usr/local/opt/readline/lib` and `/usr/local/opt/readline/include`, and it was solved. And pasted the required builds in it.

Used `stack install` again, and it worked.

---

Note:
I thought many beginners may have similar problem while installing the required tools for their use. These small ideas may help them.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/crytic/echidna/blob/master/.github/scripts/install-libff.sh